# How do I extract the right most number in a string?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have strings like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/username_with_number_14/posts/101505775425654414
https://www.facebook.com/username/posts/101505775425654466
```

I need to extract the number on the end of the string in Ruby. In the first string, it is the second and last number, whereas in the second string it is the first, only and last number.

At the moment I am extracting the number like this:

```
int1 = Regexp.new('.*?(\\d+)',Regexp::IGNORECASE).match()[1]
```

But when this is applied to the first string, it extracts the number part of the username, not the desired number.

How can I do it so that it will work on both strings?

Comment: last number means `101505775425654414` or only `4`

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do

Comment: What are you really trying to do? I think we have some XY syndrome going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
text = <<ENDTEXT
https://www.facebook.com/username_with_number_14/posts/101505775425654414
https://www.facebook.com/username/posts/101505775425654466
ENDTEXT

p text.lines.map{|line| line.scan(/\d+/).last}
#=> ["101505775425654414", "101505775425654466"]
```

Answer (score 0):

for me works regexp like this:

```
^.*?(\d+)$
```

look here: http://rubular.com/r/CJzsgjedqJ

Comment: This assumes the number is always at the very end of this string. If there could be some non-numeric characters at the end, but you still want to capture the number, use ^.*?(\d+)\D*$

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int1 = Regexp.new('.*\\/(\\d+)$',Regexp::IGNORECASE).match()[1]
```

The `$` matches the end of the string. So I put all numbers from the last `/` to the end of the string into the capturing group 1.